# Ajax request does not fire on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax to post some data to a php script. I want the ajax request to be triggered when the delete button is clicked, and then delete the div where the click button was clicked.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-blue margin-bottom-40">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>Management Panel</h3>
                    </div>                                     
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Care Home</th>
                                <th>Last Login</th>
                                <th>Number of Log-ins</th>
                                <th>Last Data Upload</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($employees as $employee)
                            <tr id="tr{{$employee->email}}">
                                <td class="fn">{{$employee->username}}</td>
                                <td class="ln">{{$employee->username}}</td>
                                <td class="email">{{$employee->email}}</td>
                                <td class="carehome_name">{{$employee->carehome_name}}</td>
                                <td class="last_login">{{$employee->last_login}}</td>
                                <td class="n_sessions">{{$employee->n_sessions}}</td>
                                <td class="last_upload">{{$employee->last_upload}}</td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="{{$employee->email}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button></span></td>                          
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

**And here is the Javascript:**

```
<script type="javscript">

  $('.btn-danger').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);

    $.ajax({
      url: '../../controllers/userManagementAjax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'action': 'delete', 'email': id},
      success: function(data, status) {
        if(data == "ok") {
          $('#tr'+'id').remove();
        }
      },

      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }


    }); // end ajax call
  });

</script>
```

I've tried a number of things and nothing works, the click event is not event logged to the the console.

Thank you all for your suggestions!

Comment: This can't be good: ` url: '../../controllers/userManagementAjax.php',`, you have to call the HTTP uri in the ajax request and I don't think you want to access your controller like that.

Comment: Even with relative paths ajax request should be made (please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xCAaQ/). Possible problem might lay with not having your script within `$(document).ready()` block. Bear in mind that `script` is evaluated as soon as it's encountered within DOM, so if your HTML code is later on I'd say that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here.

http://jsfiddle.net/py6PJ/

I removed your PHP loop, it seems to click just fine.  Please confirm.

```
<div class="container content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-blue margin-bottom-40">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>Management Panel</h3>
                    </div>                                     
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Care Home</th>
                                <th>Last Login</th>
                                <th>Number of Log-ins</th>
                                <th>Last Data Upload</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr id="tr{{$employee->email}}">
                                <td class="fn">{{$employee->username}}</td>
                                <td class="ln">{{$employee->username}}</td>
                                <td class="email">{{$employee->email}}</td>
                                <td class="carehome_name">{{$employee->carehome_name}}</td>
                                <td class="last_login">{{$employee->last_login}}</td>
                                <td class="n_sessions">{{$employee->n_sessions}}</td>
                                <td class="last_upload">{{$employee->last_upload}}</td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="{{$employee->email}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button></span></td>                          
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

Javascript is the same.